# Error in launching Gazebo in AUTOWARE?

Tags: gazebo, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Operating system and version:
Ubuntu 18.04
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
cmake version 3.10.2

Autoware installation type
Built from source

Autoware version 1.12.0-alpha2

ROS distribution:
melodic
ROS installation type:
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full
Gazebo 9

I am trying to launch gazebo using autoware and I am getting this following error:

```
/home/king/autoware/ros/install/runtime_manager/lib/runtime_manager/runtime_manager_dialog.py:2865: wxPyDeprecationgarning: Call to deprecated item. 
  wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
loading param.yaml
loading qs.yaml
Subscribe[localization] topic=/ndt_stat, key=/ndt_stat.NDTStat.exe_time
Subscribe[detection] topic=/topic2, key=/topic2
Subscribe[detection] topic=/topic1, key=/topic1
loading setup.yaml
loading map.yaml
loading sensing.yaml
loading computing.yaml
loading interface.yaml
loading data.yaml
loading simulation.yaml
['rosparam', 'set', '/use_sim_time', 'false']
loading status.yaml
loading state.yaml
loading topics.yaml

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.989: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.990: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.990: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.991: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.991: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.992: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.993: Negative content width -13 (allocation 3, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.993: Negative content width -12 (allocation 4, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.993: Negative content width -12 (allocation 4, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.994: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.994: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.995: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.995: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.995: Negative content width -1 (allocation 1, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node border, owner GtkFrame)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.995: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.995: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.995: Negative content width -1 (allocation 1, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node border, owner GtkFrame)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.995: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.995: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.995: Negative content width -1 (allocation 1, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node border, owner GtkFrame)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.995: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.995: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.995: Negative content width -1 (allocation 1, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node border, owner GtkFrame)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.995: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.995: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.995: Negative content width -1 (allocation 1, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node border, owner GtkFrame)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.995: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.995: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.996: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.996: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.996: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.996: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.996: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.996: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.996: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.996: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.997: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.997: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.999: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:46.999: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.000: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.000: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.000: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.001: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.001: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.001: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.001: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.001: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.002: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.002: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.002: Negative content height -1 (allocation 11, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content width -5 (allocation 1, extents 3x3) while allocating gadget (node scale, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content height -5 (allocation 1, extents 3x3) while allocating gadget (node scale, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: for_size smaller than min-size (0 < 3) while measuring gadget (node trough, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 23:55:47.011: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScale

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content height -2 (allocation 0, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node trough, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content width -5 (allocation 1, extents 3x3) while allocating gadget (node scale, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content height -5 (allocation 1, extents 3x3) while allocating gadget (node scale, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: for_size smaller than min-size (0 < 3) while measuring gadget (node trough, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 23:55:47.011: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScale

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content height -2 (allocation 0, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node trough, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content width -5 (allocation 1, extents 3x3) while allocating gadget (node scale, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content height -5 (allocation 1, extents 3x3) while allocating gadget (node scale, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: for_size smaller than min-size (0 < 3) while measuring gadget (node trough, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 23:55:47.011: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScale

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content height -2 (allocation 0, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node trough, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content width -5 (allocation 1, extents 3x3) while allocating gadget (node scale, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content height -5 (allocation 1, extents 3x3) while allocating gadget (node scale, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: for_size smaller than min-size (0 < 3) while measuring gadget (node trough, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 23:55:47.011: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScale

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content height -2 (allocation 0, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node trough, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.011: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.012: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.012: Negative content width -5 (allocation 1, extents 3x3) while allocating gadget (node scale, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.012: Negative content height -5 (allocation 1, extents 3x3) while allocating gadget (node scale, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.012: for_size smaller than min-size (0 < 3) while measuring gadget (node trough, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 23:55:47.012: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScale

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.012: Negative content height -2 (allocation 0, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node trough, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.012: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.012: Negative content width -5 (allocation 1, extents 3x3) while allocating gadget (node scale, owner GtkScale)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 23:55:47.012: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScale

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.014: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.014: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.014: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.014: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.014: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.015: Negative content width -15 (allocation 1, extents 8x8) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:47.015: Negative content height -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node entry, owner GtkEntry)

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:49.555: Negative content height -1 (allocation 11, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)
['sh', '-c', '$(rospack find runtime_manager)/scripts/gazebo.sh']
pid=14746
sched policy=OTHER prio=0
Failed connect to /tmp/autoware_proc_manager
pid=14749
sched policy=OTHER prio=0
Failed connect to /tmp/autoware_proc_manager
warning: xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.
warning: inconsistent namespace redefinitions for xmlns:xacro:
old: http://ros.org/wiki/xacro
new: http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro (/opt/ros/melodic/share/velodyne_description/urdf/HDL-32E.urdf.xacro)
warning: inconsistent namespace redefinitions for xmlns:xacro:
old: http://ros.org/wiki/xacro
new: http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro (/opt/ros/melodic/share/velodyne_description/urdf/VLP-16.urdf.xacro)
warning: redefining global property: pi
when processing file: /home/sai/autoware/ros/install/gazebo_camera_description/share/gazebo_camera_description/urdf/monocular_camera.xacro
included from: /home/sai/autoware/ros/install/vehicle_model/share/vehicle_model/urdf/vehicle.xacro
warning: redefining global property: pi
when processing file: /home/sai/autoware/ros/install/gazebo_imu_description/share/gazebo_imu_description/urdf/imu.xacro
included from: /home/sai/autoware/ros/install/vehicle_model/share/vehicle_model/urdf/vehicle.xacro
warning: redefining global property: pi
when processing file: /home/sai/autoware/ros/install/vehicle_model/share/vehicle_model/urdf/vehicle.xacro
warning: redefining global property: pi
when processing file: /home/sai/autoware/ros/install/vehicle_model/share/vehicle_model/urdf/vehicle.xacro
warning: redefining global property: pi
when processing file: /home/sai/autoware/ros/install/vehicle_model/share/vehicle_model/urdf/vehicle.xacro
warning: redefining global property: pi
when processing file: /home/sai/autoware/ros/install/vehicle_model/share/vehicle_model/urdf/vehicle.xacro
warning: redefining global property: pi
when processing file: /home/sai/autoware/ros/install/vehicle_model/share/vehicle_model/urdf/vehicle.xacro
warning: redefining global property: pi
when processing file: /home/sai/autoware/ros/install/vehicle_model/share/vehicle_model/urdf/vehicle.xacro
warning: redefining global property: pi
when processing file: /home/sai/autoware/ros/install/vehicle_model/share/vehicle_model/urdf/vehicle.xacro
warning: redefining global property: pi
when processing file: /home/sai/autoware/ros/install/vehicle_model/share/vehicle_model/urdf/vehicle.xacro
warning: redefining global property: pi
when processing file: /home/sai/autoware/ros/install/vehicle_model/share/vehicle_model/urdf/vehicle.xacro
warning: xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead

(runtime_manager_dialog.py:14594): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:55:52.154: Negative content height -1 (allocation 11, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)
... logging to /home/sai/.ros/log/36dad7de-9ddc-11e9-8f0d-0242c19a1927/roslaunch-sai-Blade-14751.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://sai-Blade:36717/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
* /autoware_gazebo/joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 50
* /autoware_gazebo/joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...
* /autoware_gazebo/steering_left_front_position_controller/joint: steering_left_fro...
* /autoware_gazebo/steering_left_front_position_controller/pid/d: 10.0
* /autoware_gazebo/steering_left_front_position_controller/pid/i: 100.0
* /autoware_gazebo/steering_left_front_position_controller/pid/p: 100000.0
* /autoware_gazebo/steering_left_front_position_controller/type: effort_controller...
* /autoware_gazebo/steering_right_front_position_controller/joint: steering_right_fr...
* /autoware_gazebo/steering_right_front_position_controller/pid/d: 10.0
* /autoware_gazebo/steering_right_front_position_controller/pid/i: 100.0
* /autoware_gazebo/steering_right_front_position_controller/pid/p: 100000.0
* /autoware_gazebo/steering_right_front_position_controller/type: effort_controller...
* /autoware_gazebo/vehicle_gazebo_info_publisher/enable_base_link_tf: False
* /autoware_gazebo/vehicle_gazebo_input_subscriber/ctrl_cmd: False
* /autoware_gazebo/vehicle_gazebo_input_subscriber/twist_sub: True
* /autoware_gazebo/vehicle_gazebo_input_subscriber/twiststamped: True
* /autoware_gazebo/wheel_left_rear_velocity_controller/joint: wheel_left_rear_j...
* /autoware_gazebo/wheel_left_rear_velocity_controller/pid/d: 10.0
* /autoware_gazebo/wheel_left_rear_velocity_controller/pid/i: 0.01
* /autoware_gazebo/wheel_left_rear_velocity_controller/pid/p: 10.0
* /autoware_gazebo/wheel_left_rear_velocity_controller/type: velocity_controll...
* /autoware_gazebo/wheel_right_rear_velocity_controller/joint: wheel_right_rear_...
* /autoware_gazebo/wheel_right_rear_velocity_controller/pid/d: 10.0
* /autoware_gazebo/wheel_right_rear_velocity_controller/pid/i: 0.01
* /autoware_gazebo/wheel_right_rear_velocity_controller/pid/p: 10.0
* /autoware_gazebo/wheel_right_rear_velocity_controller/type: velocity_controll...
* /gazebo/enable_ros_network: True
* /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
* /rosdistro: melodic
* /rosversion: 1.14.3
* /use_sim_time: True
* /vehicle_info/maximum_steering_angle: 97.3
* /vehicle_info/minimum_turning_radius: 2.95
* /vehicle_info/vehicle_height: 1.5
* /vehicle_info/vehicle_length: 4.82
* /vehicle_info/vehicle_mass: 5000.0
* /vehicle_info/vehicle_width: 1.81
* /vehicle_info/wheel_base: 2.95
* /vehicle_info/wheel_radius: 0.341
* /vehicle_info/wheel_tread: 1.55
* /vehicle_info/wheel_width: 0.225

NODES
/autoware_gazebo/
controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
vehicle_gazebo_info_publisher (vehicle_gazebo_simulation_interface/vehicle_gazebo_info_publisher)
vehicle_gazebo_input_subscriber (vehicle_gazebo_simulation_interface/vehicle_gazebo_input_subscriber)
/
gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
spawn_urdf (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[gazebo-1]: started with pid [14770]
process[gazebo_gui-2]: started with pid [14775]
process[spawn_urdf-3]: started with pid [14780]
process[autoware_gazebo/controller_spawner-4]: started with pid [14781]
process[autoware_gazebo/robot_state_publisher-5]: started with pid [14782]
process[autoware_gazebo/vehicle_gazebo_input_subscriber-6]: started with pid [14783]
[WARN] [1562190953.079384, 0.000000]: wait_for_service(/autoware_gazebo/controller_manager/load_controller): failed to contact, will keep trying
[ERROR] [1562190955.116131279, 0.154000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /autoware_gazebo/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/wheel_left_rear_joint
[ERROR] [1562190955.116912991, 0.154000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /autoware_gazebo/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/wheel_right_rear_joint
[Err] [REST.cc:205] Error in REST request

libcurl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'api.ignitionfuel.org'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327643/error-in-launching-gazebo-in-autoware??/) by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2019-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for reporting the bug.
I think that it has probably been fixed in the latest version.
https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/visualization/commit/2aab7e9df619e37d7576ea7fa7a7e9832fb02a88

---

Originally posted by [yukkysaito](https://answers.ros.org/users/42703/yukkysaito/) with karma: 41 on 2019-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on 2019-07-04**:
@yukkysaito That means Should I update my autoware to 1.12.0-beta.1 from present version of 1.12.0-alpha2 which I am using. If I need to update to 1.12.0-beta.1 Should I delete 1.12.0-alpha2 or If possible without deleting that is there any command to update to 1.12.0-beta1. And After UPdating to 1.12.0-beta1 DO I need to again build by Colcon?